# How to call the parent method from child in react componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I can't use my threejs methods outside of `componentDidMount` in react. But I need to use parent methods inside of this component (child), I need it to do operations with the THREE.js objects. Is there any way to get and use parent methods within the child function's `componentDidMount`?

I tried it like so in parent:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Canvas from './Canvas';
import * as THREE from 'three';

function App() {
  function Hi (){
    console.log("POOP");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>this is the story of a man</h1>
    <Canvas hi={Hi()}/>
        </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and like so in the child:

```
import './App.css';

import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

export default class CanvAs extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const hi = this.props;
var camera, scene, renderer, light;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var clock2 = new THREE.Clock();
let mixer;
let mixer2;
let player;
let Enemy;
let EnemyPositionZ;
let EnemyPositionX;
let playerPositionX;
let playerPositionZ;
var x = 0;
// var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();
animate2();

//enemyAI();


function init() {
    this.props.hi();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
    camera.position.z = 20;
    camera.position.y = 1;
    camera.scale.z = 10;
    . . .
```

Any ideas?  :O

Comment: note: i get error "cannot read 'props' of undefined. (s 'this' is not being accessed in the componenet didmount for some reason. and when using threejs anything outside of componentdidmount will cause an error. - unless im defining a function.

Comment: in your parent component inside canvas where you are passing **Hi** function,you are calling it  pass it like this once and let me know <Canvas hi={Hi}/>

Comment: thank you, that does work if I take it outside of the init function, but is there a way to make it will work inside of the init function? :o

Comment: yes you can check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from "react";

class Canvas extends React.Component{
  init(){

    console.log("okay",this.props)
    this.props.hi() //calling the hi function
  }
  render(){
    console.log("props",this.props)
    return(
      <>
      <div>i am the child comp</div>
      </>
    )
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("in compdMount",this.props.hi)
    this.init()
  }
}
export default Canvas
```

**in react class you dont need to declare a function like function init(){},you can do it simply by declaring init(){} or init=()=>{}**